# Wpf listbox to textbox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind listbox seleceted item to textbox when click i got like this

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem:
```

how to trim that or if there any alternate way just let me know.

Thanks in Advance

What I have tried:

```
txtName.Text = List.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Have you tried using `List.SelectedItem` instead? Or, even better, how about **Binding** the `SelectedItem` to your `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes I did but same result will be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override `ToString()` method in your item's class. Then it will show what ever you put in that method instead of showing its 'Type' which is the default `ToString()` result.

You could also directly bind to the `Property` of the item rather than the item itself, so that it will show the correct value (e.g. `Item.Name`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by xaml. you don't need cs code

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList"></ListBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=SelectedItem.Property}"/>
```

Don't forget to select the property that you want show

Comment: so what's the problem? if you can get selected value

Comment: When i selected a list box bind the value to textbox correctly but text box shown like "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem:"

Comment: @RKT You must select ptoperty of SelectedItem. Path=SelectedItem.YourProperty